# Dynamic programming, time complexity issue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I need to find all numbers in the interval [a,b], which satisfy two conditions:

- are divisible by k
- sum of number digits should be in the interval [c,d]
- 1 ≤ k ≤ 10^11; (1 ≤ a, b < 10^11); (1 ≤ c, b ≤ 99)

(1 ≤ k ≤ 10^11) (1 ≤ a, b < 10^11)

Naive implementation(even with improvements) is too slow. 
Can somebody help with "dynamic" realization of it?
Or maybe some useful advice & links?
I'll be grateful for the help.

Comment: What gives you the impression that dynamic programming is a way to go?

Comment: Constraints for a, b, c, d please.

Comment: Dynamic programming (DP) is based on *not* repeating the computation of partial results -- sub-computations.  This problem does not have repeated computations of any appreciable complexity.  Also, the problem is inherently linear, so I'm unclear where you believe that DP might speed up the solution.  Post your current (slow) solution?

Comment: @Rishav ~
 (1 ≤ k ≤ 10^11)
 (1 ≤ a, b < 10^11)

Comment: b ≤ 99) should be d <= 99), shouldn't it?

Comment: Dependent on some value k, you will be given, or the sum over every possible k? The sum of number digits should be 1 for the smallest number in [1..10¹¹]. If you have 11 digits of value 9, you get the biggest, possible value in [a..b] anyway. Add one, and you have 10¹¹. Every number is divisible by itself, and k is in the very same interval. So isn't the solution not just [1..(10¹¹-1)]?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that dynamic programming could help you here.
The first condition is pretty straightforward to handle -- you iterate over the [a,b] range with a step of k. So complexity is O((b-a)/k).
As for the second condition could you clarify if "b" in it is the same "b" as in first condition? If so it's pretty trivial to leverage it the result is one element or an empty list. So complexity is O(1).
If "b" is different I cannot imagine how you can improve O((b-a)/k) exploiting the second condition.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the interval in question.